# powershell move-item not working in scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to move jpg snapshots from a webcam into daily archive folders via a scheduled powershell script.

The files have the following naming scheme Snapshot-yyyymmdd-hhmmss.jpg and all files of a single day should be moved into a yyyy-mm-dd directory.

So I created the following script that works as expected when called from the PS command prompt, but not from the windows task scheduler:

```
$day_yesterday = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$filename = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$source = 'E:\WebCam\jpg\Snapshot-'+ $filename + '-*.jpg'
$destination = 'E:\WebCam\jpg\'+$day_yesterday

if (!(Test-Path -path $destination)){
   New-Item -Path E:\WebCam\jpg\ -Name $day_yesterday -ItemType directory
}
move-item $source -Destination $destination
```

When called from a scheduled task, the target directory is created, but the move-item commandlet silently fails, all files stay in the source directory.

Any ideas are appreciated...

Comment: Does the account your running the scheduled task as have full access to both the source and destination folder? Have you tried using the 'Run with highest privileges' setting? Also try using `-Force` on the `move-item`.

Comment: Is E:\ a mapped drive that is only available when you are logged in?

Comment: Thanks Richard -  'Run with highest privileges' did the trick!

Comment: Dave, source and target are both local drives on the same machine that runs the script.